# How would one reduce HaltTM to ATM

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions

Assuming that ATM is decidable, how to build a TM S that uses a TM R that takes as input  and decides if M accepts w, to decide HaltTM, which we already know is undecidable, hence ATM isn't decidable.   So how exactly do we go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A reduction of $HALT_{TM}$ to $A_{TM}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83696/a-reduction-of-halt-tm-to-a-tm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of argument we will assume $A_{TM}$ is decidable. Now we are going to show a way to decide $HALT_{TM}$ using a decider for $A_{TM}$ and thus reach a contradiction, since we know $HALT_{TM}$ is undecidable.

Details:

If $A_{TM}$ is decidable, then its complement $\overline{A_{TM}}$ is also decidable. Suppose TM $R$ decides $A_{TM}$ and $S$ decides $\overline{A_{TM}}$. We use those to build TM $X$ that takes input $\left<M, w\right>$, a TM description $M$ and input $w$.

1. Run $R$ on $\left<M, w\right>$.
2. If $R$ accepts, then $X$ accepts.
3. If $R$ rejects, then run $S$ on $\left<M, w\right>$.
4. If $S$ accepts, then $X$ accepts.
5. If $S$ rejects, then $X$ rejects.

Thus, $X$ will reject only machines that do not halt and will accept all others. So we have used a decider for $A_{TM}$ to construct a decider for $HALT_{TM}$. But $HALT_{TM}$ is undecidable, so we conclude that $A_{TM}$ is undecidable.

Comment: The answer is incomplete.

Comment: The answer is complete, but for some reason it's concealed. If I try to edit the answer I see it all, but when I save it then all words after ", given input" disappear.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. there was "input<M,w)" which some how confused the editor or something, some spaces and changing ")" to ">" seem to have solved the issue. Thank you Reeshabh for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: The angle brackets probably would have been parsed as HTML tags, which can cause all kinds of weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

Let R be a TM that decides ATM.

Build a new machine G =

```
"On input x:

For i = 1,2,...

Simulate M for i steps.

If M halted before the i'th step, accept.

Otherwise, continue to next i iteration."
```

Now run R on input (G,42).
if R accets, accept. if R rejects, reject.

Note 42 is arbirtary (G completely ignores input x anyway).

Explanation: This R will accept iff G accepts, but G accepts iff M halts on w after some i steps.